# Get the value of select class options

Tags: javascript, html, select, html-select, getelementbyid

I'm working on a test/quiz and I can't solve a problem.

I like to grab the selected value from a option and print it to the result p.

```
 <div class="add">
            <div class="add__container">
                <select class="add__type">
                    <option value="0" id="a01" selected>No</option>
                    <option value="1" id="a02">Ocassionally</option>
                    <option value="2" id="a03">Yes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

    <button class="btn" onclick="myValue()">Results</button>
    <p id="result">... </p>
```

And here is my Javascript code where I'm stucked:

```
function myValue(){    
var e = document.getElementById("s01");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = e;

};
```

Comment: since you are new, hello and welcome. try putting this code in a sandbox and link that here. that will make it easy for the community to run the code directly, see the error and help you faster.

Comment: `.innerHTML = e;` <-- well you are not outputting the text/value....   `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = value;` You have no element with the id of `"s01"`. Use your developer console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code. I think this code work like you requirement.

```js
function myValue(){    
        var select = document.getElementsByClassName("add__type")[0].value;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = select;
};
```

```html
 <div class="add">
            <div class="add__container">
                <select class="add__type">
                    <option value="0" id="a01" selected>No</option>
                    <option value="1" id="a02">Ocassionally</option>
                    <option value="2" id="a03">Yes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

    <button class="btn" onclick="myValue()">Results</button>
    <p id="result">... </p>
```

[something more..](https://one7techlab.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put the actual text of the selected option in the innerHtml instead of the option DOM element:

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this? I added the id "s01" on select.

```
<div class="add">
    <div class="add__container">
        <select id="s01" class="add__type">
            <option value="0" id="a01" selected>No</option>
            <option value="1" id="a02">Ocassionally</option>
            <option value="2" id="a03">Yes</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<button class="btn" onclick="myValue()">Results</button>
<p id="result">... </p>
<script>
    function myValue() {
        var e = document.getElementById("s01");
        var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text;

    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Unimportant stuff

const $ = document;
$.get = $.getElementById;

$.get('theOptions').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  // Get the value from the select-element
  $.get('out').innerHTML = 'You selected ' + event.target.value; // Or $.get('theOptions').value
});
```

```html
<select id="theOptions">
  <option value="o1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="o2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="o3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<span id="out">Nothing selected</span>
```